# sudo -u ignoring command arguments

Tags: linux, sudo

```
sudo -u app forever start -p /logs -l /logs/forever.log -o /logs/out.log
```

However, the arguments do not make it to the `forever` program. How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that that's what's going wrong? I've never encountered such a problem with `sudo -u`. Is `forever` giving an error-message that implies it's not receiving enough arguments? It may be worth consulting the `forever` manual page to make sure you're not missing any arguments you need . . .

Comment: Are you certain they're not being passed?  Why do you think so? What error are you getting?  Add `echo` before `forever` and see if it prints the correct command.

Comment: I just tested `sudo -u sarnold java Echo one two three` with a dirt-simple `Echo` program I wrote for showing arguments and it appeared to work exactly as I expected. Are you _certain_ you're seeing the behavior you think you're seeing?

Comment: I get this behaviour too. And using echo it goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
sudo -u app sh -c "app forever start -p /logs -l /logs/forever.log -o /logs/out.log"
```